# Remove duplicate objects from array always returning nth index

Tags: javascript, filter, duplicates

Is there a way to remove dupilicates making sure that the nth index is always left.
So if I have

```
[{name: "john", age:20},{name:"john", age:30}]
```

I would need the result to always be

```
[{name:"john",age:30}]
```

currently, I'm using this method of removing dups

```
  PICKER.saveSelection = PICKER.saveSelection.filter((select, index, self) => {
 return self.map(function(mapItem){ return mapItem["category"]; }).indexOf(select["category"]) === index;});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `reduce` and group the array into an object using the name as the key. Use `Object.values` to convert back the object into an array.

```js
var arr = [
      {name: "john", age:20},
      {name:"john", age:30},
      {name:"adam", age:30},
      {name:"eddie", age:27}
];

var result = Object.values(arr.reduce((c, v) => Object.assign(c, {[v.name]: v}), {}));

console.log(result);
```